# LINQ query with left outer join

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I saw several of these examples and I think I am doing the syntax correctly, but I am getting an error that is not intuitive (to me anyway).

The `customersIds` come in as a string that is a comma separated list and here is my code:

```
        customerIds = "," + customerIds + ",";
        var customerRebills = context.Shipments.AsNoTracking().Where(x => customerIds.IndexOf("," + x.CustomerId + ",") >= 0)
            .Join(context.Customers.AsNoTracking(),
                im => im.CustomerId,
                cu => cu.CustomerId,
                (im, cu) => new { Shipments = im, Customers = cu }).DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Join(context.Suppliers.AsNoTracking(),
                im => im.Shipments.SupplierId,
                su => su.SupplierId,
                (im, su) => new { Shipments = im.Shipments, Customers = im.Customers, Suppliers = su }).DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Join(context.MatchingAssignments.AsNoTracking(),
                im => new {im.Shipments.TrackingNumber, im.Shipments.CarrierInvoiceNumber},
                ma => new { ma.TrackingNumber, ma.CarrierInvoiceNumber},
                (im, ma) => new { Shipments = im.Shipments, Suppliers = im.Suppliers, Customers = im.Customers, MatchingAssignments = ma }).DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Join(context.MatchResolutions.AsNoTracking(),
                ma => ma.MatchingAssignments.MatchReasonId,
                mr => mr.MatchResolutionId,
                (ma, mr) => new { MatchingAssignments = ma.MatchingAssignments, Shipments = ma.Shipments, Suppliers = ma.Suppliers, Customers = ma.Customers, MatchResolutions = mr }).DefaultIfEmpty()
            .GroupJoin(context.RebillingNotes.AsNoTracking(),
                im => new {im.Shipments.TrackingNumber, im.Shipments.CarrierInvoiceNumber},
                rn => new {rn.TrackingNumber, rn.InvoiceNumber},
                (im, rn) => new { MatchingAssignments = im.MatchingAssignments, Shipments = im.Shipments, Suppliers = im.Suppliers, MatchResolutions = im.MatchResolutions, Customers = im.Customers, RebillingNotes = rn })
            .SelectMany(
                x => x.RebillingNotes.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (x, y) => new {MatchingAssignments = x.MatchingAssignments, Shipments = x.Shipments, Suppliers = x.Suppliers, MatchingResolutions = x.MatchResolutions, Customers = x.Customers, RebillingNotes = y})
```

This code works fine when the last join is on one field:

```
            .GroupJoin(context.RebillingNotes.AsNoTracking(),
                im => im.Shipments.TrackingNumber, 
                rn => rn.TrackingNumber, 
                (im, rn) => new { MatchingAssignments = im.MatchingAssignments, Shipments = im.Shipments, Suppliers = im.Suppliers, MatchResolutions = im.MatchResolutions, Customers = im.Customers, RebillingNotes = rn })
            .SelectMany(
                x => x.RebillingNotes.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (x, y) => new {MatchingAssignments = x.MatchingAssignments, Shipments = x.Shipments, Suppliers = x.Suppliers, MatchingResolutions = x.MatchResolutions, Customers = x.Customers, RebillingNotes = y})
```

I thought it was a matter of creating objects containing the multiple fields.

The error I am receiving is:

> CS0411    The type arguments for method 'Queryable.GroupJoin(IQueryable, IEnumerable,
>   Expression>, Expression>,
>   Expression, TResult>>)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Thank you

Comment: Add the entire StackTrace of the exception to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, it was the field names in the joins.

This was causing the issue:

```
im => new {im.Shipments.TrackingNumber, im.Shipments.CarrierInvoiceNumber},
rn => new {rn.TrackingNumber, rn.InvoiceNumber},
```

This corrected the issue:

```
im => new {im.Shipments.TrackingNumber, im.Shipments.CarrierInvoiceNumber},
rn => new {rn.TrackingNumber, CarrierInvoiceNumber = rn.InvoiceNumber},
```